# How do i access the X and Y coordinates from a OpenCV Point?

Tags: python, class, opencv

So i am using **OpenCV** to do pose estimation. the function returns an array of objects which are used to draw a wireframe skeleton on video footage:

```
 #SKELETON DRAWING
        if points[idFrom] and points[idTo]:

            if i == 1:
                print(type(point[idFrom]))
                #glUniform1f(xM, float(point[idFrom][0]/width))
                #glUniform1f(yM, float(point[idFrom][1]/height))
            else:
                cv.line(frame, points[idFrom], points[idTo], (0, 255, 0), 3)
                cv.ellipse(frame, points[idFrom], (3, 3), 0, 0, 360, (0, 0, 255), cv.FILLED)
                cv.ellipse(frame, points[idTo], (3, 3), 0, 0, 360, (0, 0, 255), cv.FILLED)
```

I need to get the x and y coordinates of the points on the skeleton, and i cant figure out how to do that.
the points are apparently a <class 'int'>.
I tried using point[idFrom][0], it gives me this error: *print(type(point[idFrom][0]))
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable*

here's how the points are created:

```
 points = []
    for i in range(len(BODY_PARTS)):
        # Slice heatmap of corresponging body's part.
        heatMap = out[0, i, :, :]

        # Originally, we try to find all the local maximums. To simplify a sample
        # we just find a global one. However only a single pose at the same time
        # could be detected this way.
        _, conf, _, point = cv.minMaxLoc(heatMap)
        x = (frameWidth * point[0]) / out.shape[3]
        y = (frameHeight * point[1]) / out.shape[2]
        # Add a point if it's confidence is higher than threshold.
        points.append((int(x), int(y)) if conf > thr else None)

    i = 0
```

Comment: i dont know where u are trying to use line `type(point[idFrom][0])`, but you should use `points[0][0]` for x coordinate and `points[0][1]` for getting y coordinate.

Comment: nope, not working: print(point[idFrom][0])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: pay attention you should use `points`, not `point`.